# Are the rolls at 'Ryans' or 'Golden Corral' a style of bread?

Tags: bread, rolls

I've been looking for a recipe online to replicate the rolls you'd find at a 'Ryans' or 'Golden Corral'. I've tried several that sound promising, only to have them turn out tasting like another type of bread. Everyone seems to have the general consensus that they're yeast rolls, but those come in many forms.

I recently tried a recipe that sounded promising, because it had sugar in it and I know that they are a little sweet. However, when I cooked them, they tasted like the 'Parkerhouse' rolls and the texture wasn't correct. It's like if you squeezed these, they'd almost crumble, where they ones I want will almost mold into your hand when you squeeze them. I'll try to include a picture in this post.

My question is what makes this bread the way it is? Is it a style of bread, is it the manner in which its cooked, like with a water bath or something, or would it be the ingredients that affected this aspect.

These are delicious rolls, several restaurants have them, so it's not a secret recipe, and I'd like to narrow down my search for the correct recipe.

Here is a pic of the ones I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a page on [Ellen's Kitchen](http://www.ellenskitchen.com/forum/messages/6918.html)  with copycat recipes for the rolls from Ryan's, Golden Corral, and Logan's Roadhouse.

I have not tried these recipes yet but I found it interesting how different they are.

Comment: I believe that the 'Golden Corral' recipe on this page is the one I mentioned making. I'm not sure about the 'Ryan's' version, but the fact that they mentioned how to make clover leaf versions of them makes me suspicious. Every time I've ever had a clover leaf roll, it was good, but nothing like a Ryan's roll. I'm not sure about the 'Logan's'. I may give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

They are just simply yeast rolls that have a little extra sugar for the American palate.

Here is a decent base recipe: http://allrecipes.com/recipe/quick-yeast-rolls/

I'd recommend reading the most helpful critical reviews at the bottom because with the tweaks mentioned, they taste amazing.

Comment: I'm definitely going to try that recipe, but from the picture, it looks like they'll be similar in texture to the ones I made last weekend. The ones at these restaurants a very soft and almost chewy. I added a picture to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: double the sugar, 1.5x on the yeast and let it rise a little longer. Also up temp to about 460 to get the truly fluffy texture. Also add 1/4 tsp of baking powder (not soda)